# Change DNS server details in network card

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

I am trying to change DNS server on NIC card. Some of machines have more than 1 NIC (LAN) card. So far I have created below script.

```
$servers = Get-Content .\Server.txt
$DNSServers = "8.8.8.8","2.2.2.2"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -ea 0) {
    $prisecdns = Get-WMIObject -Query "select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled = true and DHCPEnabled = False and ipconnectionmetric = 1" -ComputerName $server

    $prisecdns.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers)
    $prisecdns.SetDynamicDNSRegistration("TRUE")
    ipconfig /flushDns | Out-Null 
    Write-Host "DNS Cache Flushed" -ForegroundColor Green 

    # Register the DNS 
    ipconfig /registerdns | Out-Null 
    Write-Host "DNS Regsitered" -ForegroundColor Green 
  }
}
```

I am not sure above script will work properly in case of multiple network adapters.

Can anybody advise me on this?

**Powershell version is 2.**

Comment: How about you test it and come back if you find that something actually doesn't work?

Comment: I tested it on single adapter and it is working fine. Unfortunatly, I don't have multiple adapter in my machine.

Comment: And you're unable to create a test VM with multiple adapters (e.g. in VirtualBox), because ...?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Got your point. Thanks. I will delete this question.

Comment: @404 No need to delete the question. Just update it with your findings. It may be of use to someone else.

Comment: I already given all the information